# How does a virtual machine execute instructions?

Tags: c#, java, jvm, clr

I have a strong C++ background and never really had a deep understanding of Java or C#. However, I am curious about the internal workings of the virtual machines. I've experimented with some windows exes and figured out that the actual virtual machines are the jvm and the clr dynamic libraries.

Now here is what bothers me: **How do these libraries interact with the instructions in an exe file?**

My only guess is that the bytecode is actually stored in the .data segment of the exe file. And it actually passes control to the .dll, which translates the bytecode instructions. Is that correct?

I was unable to find anything about the subject so any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you're interested in the JVM you might like this talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL2D3qzHtqY

Comment: The Java JVM does not execute exe files.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. That's exactly the magic I'm trying to understand. For instance Eclipse runs on JVM right? And still you launch it through an exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess about where the IL is stored is addressed here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#.NET.2C_metadata.2C_and_the_PE_format

Your conjecture is basically correct for C#. The executable starts up the CLR and hands off the metadata and IL; the CLR then figures out where "Main" is, grabs the IL for that, jit-compiles it into x86 (or whatever) code, and runs that. Each method is compiled "just in time" before it runs for the first time, hence the term "jit compiler".

That is of course a greatly simplified overview. If you want more information about how .NET works, start with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4t23ktk.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Well, at the most basic level you got that right: There is a native application (the runtime, such as `java.exe`) that reads the bytecode and "runs" it by interpreting the instructions contained within.

The first adjustment you have to make to that picture is that for performance reasons, most VM now use JIT-compilation, which means that the bytecode is not interpreted, but compiled into native code on the fly.

> My only guess is that the bytecode is actually stored in the .data segment of the exe file.

Depends. For Java, you usually just have a JAR file with the bytecode, separated from the native binary that gets launched. But, yes, you could combine that together into a single executable, that would then contain the native launcher code (but probably not all the shared libraries that depends on), and the bytecode "as data".

> For instance Eclipse runs on JVM right? And still you launch it through an exe.

Yes. Eclipse has one of these "launch wrapper exe". But if you look at that, it is very small. All it does is put up a splash screen and launch the JVM (installed on your system, not part of the exe), and throws some JAR files at it (installed as part of Eclipse, but not inside the exe either).